# How to interpret two distinguishable particles with N possible states?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

NOTE: Please do not provide an answer to the questions. If I am incorrect, please explain why, and if I am correct, please try to further my understanding. I think that this is a constructive way to both help others reading this question and also to help me solve the problem myself.

Imagine we have a box with N single-particle states, each having zero energy. Suppose now we have 1 particle.

My solution to the partition function is as follows:

$$Z=\sum_{s=1}^{N}\Omega(s)e^{-\beta E(s)}=\sum_{s=1}^{N}1\times e^0=1\times N=N.$$

($\beta=1/k_BT$, s is the number of states, $\Omega(s)$ is the multiplicity per single-particle state.) Since there are N single-particle states, the multiplicity is 1 for each state, thus the logic behind the solution above. Correct?

Now imagine the same situation but with 2 distinguishable particles. At any point in time, two single-particle states will be occupied. When they switch, this is a situation that looks different because the particles are distinguishable, thus making the multiplicity become $\Omega(s)=2$. This gives the partition function as $$Z=\sum_{s=1}^{N}\Omega(s)e^{-\beta E(s)}=\sum_{s=1}^{N}2\times e^0=2\times N=2N.$$

Please take into account the paragraph at the top when answering. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a tricky question for you: When both particles are in the same single particle state, do you get a new state when you exchange them? :)

Comment: How can two particles be in the same single-particle state? I thought that, by definition, a single-particle state only allows 1 particle to occupy at at a given time...